# Check Value exist in array

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have a list of employees who are allowed for manager level salary. When salary is paid to an employee, I have to check, is the person is in the manager level salary list or not. If the employee is in the list the program return true and if not, return false. I would like to use php to solve this case how should I do? I think I should use array format but I have no idea how to solve this.

Manager level employee list is store in a variable with comma separated like this:

```
$a=12312,23421,12342,12342
```

Comment: So basically, you want to use a language you can't work with. I'm sorry to be blunt, but you can't work out how to do this in PHP, even if [the manual](http://www.php.net) is full of examples, and is easy to navigate ***and*** the functions have pretty telling names, like [`in_array`](http://www.php.net/in_array) or `array_search` and `array_key_exists`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use `explode()` to convert the string to `array()` then `in_array()` to check whether id exist or not.

```
$a='12312,23421,12342,12342';
$arr = array_filter(explode(',', $a));
$id = '12312';
if(in_array($id, $arr)){
    echo 'Exist';
}
```

Comment: Please don't answer to questions like this. Don't encourage the bad kind of laziness. The OP should show at least _some_ effort, _some_ evidence of basic research. Answering these questions encourages low-quality questions being asked, so please, don't. All the more because the OP probably doesn't accept/up-vote answers (~= leeching)

Comment: Thank you very much! It helps me completely:)